# Namespace error while validation schema with StAXSource

Tags: java, xml, validation, stax

I'm try to validate an XML using StAX and javax Validator however I'm getting the following cast error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt.NamespaceEventImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt.NamespaceEventImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The basic idea is that I need to parse an XML using StAX and I'm attempting to reuse the event reader I'll be using for parsing and creating a StAXSource to perform the validation.

I was able to debug the error and trace the cast exception to the class com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXEvent2SAX, line 341, where there is a loop through an iterator and a cast to a String when in fact the iterator has the type NamespaceEventImpl (snippet code of the portion of code below).

```
        // end namespace bindings
        for( Iterator i = event.getNamespaces(); i.hasNext();) {
            String prefix = (String)i.next();
            if( prefix == null ) { // true for default namespace
                prefix = "";
            }
            _sax.endPrefixMapping(prefix);
        }
```

The following is the content of the iterator "i" while performing the logic I'm referring to:
[iterator content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRNYi.png)

Below is a snippet of code describing how I'm doing it.

```
public void validateRequest(RequestMessage message) {
    try {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getMessage().getBytes()));

        this.validateSchema(eventReader);

        if(this.isSchemaValid()) {
            // parse through XML
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void validateSchema(XMLEventReader eventReader) {
    try {
        StAXErrorHandler errorHandler = new StAXErrorHandler();
        this.validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        this.validator.validate(new StAXSource(eventReader));
    } catch (SAXException | IOException | XMLStreamException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if someone faced this issue before and if it is a limitation of using StAXSource with the Validator itself.